# Change Android Shashlik simulator input language

Tags: android, linux, simulator

I installed [Shashlik](http://www.shashlik.io/) an android simulator for linux. It has minimal interface. The only way to interact with it through adb.

So, the language used is Latin.

```
adb shell ime list -s

com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME
```

How to change the physical keyboard input language?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sanapeli.adbchangelanguage

Comment: Probably a question better suited for [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/).